# Format number with two decimals, but without thousand separator

Tags: string, vb.net, format, decimal

I am grabbing data from excel spreadsheet and looking to format it in a certain way before I store it as a string.

The formatting of excel cell is to have 2 decimal places - an example of a value is:

```
283,323.20
```

This is how I grab the value:

```
Dim HoldValue as String
If Not ([String].IsNullOrEmpty(CStr(excel.Cells(Row, Column).Value)) Or CStr(excel.Cells(Row, Column).Value) = "") Then
     HoldValue = CStr(excel.Cells(Row, Column).Value)
End If
```

However, doing it this way gets rid of the last 0 so the number looks like this, which is almost what I want:

```
283323.2
```

I tried to do something like:

```
Dim HoldDecValue As Decimal= CDEC(excel.Cells(Row, Column).Value)
```

and:

```
Holdvalue = HoldDecValue.ToString("N2")
```

which makes it look like this:

```
283,323.20
```

but my goal is to make it look like this:

```
283323.20
```

Comment: [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#FFormatString)

Comment: Dim HoldTotal_SPEND As Double = CDbl(excel.Cells(Row, Column).Value)
strHoldTOTAL = (HoldTotal.ToString("F")) This did it @plutonix thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the suggestion from Plutonix - I was able to do it...

```
Dim HoldTotal_SPEND As Double = CDbl(excel.Cells(Row, Column).Value) strHoldTOTAL = (HoldTotal.ToString("F"))
```